# T-SQL pivot with more then one non-pivot columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have several columns and making pivot. I want to have multiple non-pivot columns and to make pivot using the last one. In the original specification [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) it is shown that you can have only one non-pivot column.

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,

    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,

    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,

    ...

    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>

FROM

    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)

    AS <alias for the source query>

PIVOT

(

    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)

FOR

[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]

    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],

    ... [last pivoted column])

) AS <alias for the pivot table>

<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Is there a way to have more non-pivot columns, because it is pivoting my data using all columns after the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just add them.

eg

```
declare @t table (a int, b int, c int, d int)
insert @t values (1,2,3,4)
insert @t values (7,6,5,3)

select a,b, [3],[4] from @t s
pivot 
(sum(c) for d in ([3],[4])) p
```